# how to put values in grails select tag manually

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

how to put values in select tag in grails.

```
 <g:select name="country_name" > </g:select>
```

like all country name USA,UK,AUS,SA,CAN,INDIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<g:select name="country_name" from="${['USA','UK','INDIA']}"> </g:select>
```

through this you can put values manually

```
from="${['USA','UK','INDIA']}
```